# document.getElementById("clock") is null

Tags: jquery, time, clock

i have a clock time inside my form..it run as a current time same with PC time..
i'm use this code:

```
    <script language="javascript">
            var int=self.setInterval("clock()",1000);
            function clock()
                             {
                                var d=new Date();
                                document.getElementById("clock").value=d.getHours() + ":"+d.getMinutes()+ ":" +d.getSeconds();
                           }
      </script>

<input type="text" id="clock" name="time">
```

but after click submit the clock automatically pause...and show error at firebugs `document.getElementById("clock") is null`...
how to make it works normally by using jquery code?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/eceku3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to ask here, but this is the "jQuery" version of what you're doing:

```
function updateClock() {
  var d=new Date();
  $("#clock").val(d.getHours() + ":"+d.getMinutes()+ ":" +d.getSeconds());
}
setInterval(updateClock,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside document ready function in jquery.

```
$(function(){
    var interval=self.setInterval("clock()",1000); 

    function clock() 
    { 
        var d=new Date(); 
        $("#clock").val(d.getHours() + ":"+d.getMinutes()+ ":" +d.getSeconds()); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: this will not work, unless you change `self.setInterval("clock()",1000);` to `self.setInterval(clock,1000);`